# UI path write multiple column in excel

Tags: excel, uipath

I am learning UIPath and my source is excel file. I have excel file with column A,B, C. What I want is to write column A and C only into new excel file.

I get confused which function I should use to read / write. I think if I use read range / write range, it will write all column. However, what I want is only column A and C

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire Excel sheet with ReadRange. It outputs a Datatable. For DataTables there is an activity called Remove Data Column (Programming->DataTable). Use this to remove Col B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,First Read all the excel Data using the read range activity in the activity panel and then go for the for each row activity to get each and specific values and then you can drag and drop the write cell Activity from the activity Panel.and in write cell mention the Sheet Name,Range in which you need to start from and value which means which value you wanted to print 
for example:you want only A and c Means you can go for row(0).ToString and row(2).ToString..
if you find any challenge in doing this,Fell Free to let me know.:D